# Issue in a time series ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I have a data like this:

```
df<-structure(list(Participant.ID = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "83528", class = "factor"), 
    Response = c("2", "1", "0", "1", "3", "3", "5", "3", "5", 
    "6", "3", "5", "7", "3", "6", "2", "3", "3", "3", "3", "5", 
    "4", "3", "1", "4", "4", "3", "6", "3"), times = c(1, 2, 
    3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 
    19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29)), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -29L), groups = structure(list(
    Participant.ID = structure(1L, .Label = "1", class = "factor"), 
    .rows = structure(list(1:29), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -1L), .drop = TRUE))
```

Using this code, I plotted a time series, but the outcome was not a time series, and the lines overlapped each other. Where is the problem? Thanks!

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = times, y = Response)) + 
  geom_line(aes(color = Participant.ID), size = 1)  +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your `Response` column is a character. By default `ggplot2` will group your data by a discrete columns. Hence you get a line for each category of `Response`.

To fix that you could convert your `Response` column to a numeric or override the default grouping by mapping `Participant.ID` on the `group` aes

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(x = times, y = as.numeric(Response))) +
  geom_line(aes(color = Participant.ID), size = 1) +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x = times, y = Response, group = Participant.ID)) +
  geom_line(aes(color = Participant.ID), size = 1) +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]